# Diagnosing JS model binder issue in mvc from ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can't figure out why my action param is coming through null. I'm also not sure of how to even diagnose the issue. I can see the http request data being sent with data and stepping through the debugger shows the object as null, not sure how to see the steps in between.

Models

```
    public class ComplexObj
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Test1 { get; set; }
        public decimal Test2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class BiggerObj
    {
        public BiggerObj()
        {
            ComplexObj = new List<ComplexObj>();
        }

        public long OtherId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ComplexObj> ComplexObjs { get; set; }
    }
```

Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void TestAction(BiggerObj[] biggerObjs)
    {
        ...// biggerObjs is null :(
    }
```

View

```
    function ajaxCall() {
        var data = [];

                var bigObj = new Object();
                bigObj.OtherId = 123;
                bigObj.Name = "TestName";
                bigObj.ComplexObj = [];

                var complexObj = new Object();
                complexObj.Id = 789;
                complexObj.Test1 = 123;
                complexObj.Test2 = 456;

                bigObj.ComplexObj.push(complexObj);

                data.push(bigObj);
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: SITEROOT + "myController/TestAction",
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            complete: function() {
                alert('done');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

You must use:

- `JSON.stringify` and declare the `contentType` as `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`
- Parse the decimal value by using `parseFloat() function`, decimal is considered as int by default binder.

Change your Action to this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TestAction(BiggerObj[] biggerObjs)
        {            
            ...// biggerObjs is null :(
        }
```

Change your ajaxCall function to this:

```
//ajaxCall 
function ajaxCall() {
        var data = [];

        var bigObj = {
            OtherId : 123,
            Name : "TestName",
            ComplexObjs : new Array()
        };

        var ComplexObjs = {
            Id: 789,
            Test1: 123,
            Test2: parseFloat(456) 
// decimal types are considered an integer, you have to parse
        };

        bigObj.ComplexObjs.push(ComplexObjs);

        data.push(bigObj);


        $.ajax({
            url:"/Test/TestAction",
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            complete: function () {
                alert('done');
            }
        });
    }
```

I tested, works fine.